# decoding Microsoft Safelink URL in Python

Tags: python, urldecode

```
import re
import urllib
import HTMLParser

urlRegex = re.compile(r'(.+)&data=')
match=urlRegex.search('https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Foffice.memoriesflower.com%2FPermission%2F%2525%2524%255E%2526%2526*%2523%2523%255E%2524%2525%255E%2526%255E*%2526%2523%255E%2525%2525%2526%2540%255E*%2523%2526%255E%2525%2523%2526%2540%2525*%255E%2540%255E%2523%2525%255E%2540%2526%2525*%255E%2540%2Foffice.php&data=01%7C01%7Cdavid.levin%40mheducation.com%7C0ac9a3770fe64fbb21fb08d50764c401%7Cf919b1efc0c347358fca0928ec39d8d5%7C0&sdata=PEoDOerQnha%2FACafNx8JAep8O9MdllcKCsHET2Ye%2B4%3D&reserved=0')

x = match.group()
urlRegex_1 = re.compile(r'url=(.+)&data=')
match_1 = urlRegex_1.search(x)
print match1.group(1)
htmlencodedurl = urllib.unquote(urllib.unquote(match1.group(1)))
actual_url = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(htmlencodedurl)
```

So the 'actual_url' displays this:
'https://office.memoriesflower.com/Permission/%$^&&*##^$%^&^*&#^%%&@^*#&^%'

I need it to display this:

```
https://office.memoriesflower.com/Permission/office.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is cleaner as it uses the urlparse to extract the query string and then uses path operations to remove the unwanted component:

```
import posixpath as path
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlunparse
url = 'https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Foffice.memoriesflower.com%2FPermission%2F%2525%2524%255E%2526%2526*%2523%2523%255E%2524%2525%255E%2526%255E*%2526%2523%255E%2525%2525%2526%2540%255E*%2523%2526%255E%2525%2523%2526%2540%2525*%255E%2540%255E%2523%2525%255E%2540%2526%2525*%255E%2540%2Foffice.php&data=01%7C01%7Cdavid.levin%40mheducation.com%7C0ac9a3770fe64fbb21fb08d50764c401%7Cf919b1efc0c347358fca0928ec39d8d5%7C0&sdata=PEoDOerQnha%2FACafNx8JAep8O9MdllcKCsHET2Ye%2B4%3D&reserved=0'
target = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['url'][0]
p = urlparse(target)
q = p._replace(path=path.join(path.dirname(path.dirname(p.path)), path.basename(p.path)))
print urlunparse(q)
```

prints `https://office.memoriesflower.com/Permission/office.php`

Comment: Nice. Thank you.
The python 3 version needs urllib instead of urlparse, so substitute:
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs, urlunparse

Comment: Does not work for certain URL. `p._replace` removes `/news/` in `https://www.dep.chk/government/news/international-travel-country-listings-update` from `https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dep.chk%2Fgovernment%2Fnews%2Finternational-travel-country-listings-update&data=04%7C01%7CAnd.thisdnc%40us.gov%7Ca34fbd2b81454d0cf2e208d9589fd589%7C07ef1208413c4b5e9cdd64ef305754f0%7C0%7C0%7C637638265927653873%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=2ZiClLR1v%2BWqlYT65T39oCUnQ1FUfIFssgz67P32pW4%3D&reserved=0`

Comment: @Ajned Then use one less `path.dirname`. This code was mostly an example about how to properly parse URLs, not was not meant to work on all safe link protection URL as it was only tested on the example given.

Answer (score 0):

I found this having a similar problem.  Here's the code I used to resolve the issue.  It's not particularly elegant, but you may be able to tweak it for your needs.

```
self.urls = (re.findall("safelinks\.protection\.outlook\.com/\?url=.*?sdata=", self.body.lower(), re.M))
if len(self.urls) > 0:
    for i, v in enumerate(self.urls):
        self.urls[i] = v[38:-11]
```

This works by getting the value in an ugly format and then stripping off the excess pieces of each item as a string.  I believe the proper way to do this is with grouping, but this worked well enough for my needs.